# modify Drush uli returned URL string of to include port?

Tags: drush, users

I want to modify a variable (preferably in a Bash Script format) because my PHP environment requires a port number.

To open a browser in Drush, one executes

```
$ drush uli
```

In a script:

```
$ bash-3.2$ VAR='drush uli'; echo ${VAR}; ${VAR}
```

outputs:

> drush uli

```
http:/ /website-7-26-2-17-res124725.local/user/reset/1/1393147909/zMiquSr_ikA7xdp7kA3g4CvTGd82mWsVdqEiMCs/login
```

Can I modify that URL before Drush opens the browser?

Can I stop it from executing and manipulate the URL in a Bash script?

Answer (score 2):

You can create [settings.local.php](http://brockboland.com/drupaldork/2011/11/local-settings-development-sites.html) with your development [base url](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/dc791ec5839b52c7616bf66993122aa9a1336384:/sites/default/default.settings.php#l247):

```
$base_url = 'http://website-7-26-2-17-res124725.local:8888';  // NO trailing slash!
```

Drush just uses Drupal's `url()` function to build user one-time-login link.

Comment: is there a way to set it via cli or script? like drush vset base_url?

Comment: I don't have access to settings.local.php, I need to do it via Drush or Bash Script.